# How to prevent repeatable output in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have create three rows of data in mysql database which have four column **dtfrom,dtto,timeout,timein**

And I have three sets of row

```
dtfrom      dtto        timeout     timein
2016-11-11  2016-11-11  0830     1030
2016-11-12  2016-11-12  0830     1030
2016-11-13  2016-11-13  0830     1030
```

However, the output of **"Time not passed !"** display three times like below

**Time not passed ! Time not passed ! Time not passed !**

What I want is the error **"Time not passed!"** display only once for all the query. Because there's is problem if i have hundred of data rows. The errors will appear in hundred of time isn't it ?

And the second issues is it **cannot run the error if the input is 0845 - 1730 or 0845 - 0945** . **It only run the error if the input is exactly as in database 0830 - 1030**

Can someone help ? The code as below

```
<?php
    $connect      = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
    global $connect;   

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
        $user_id        = $_POST['user_id'];

        $dtfrom         = $_POST['dtfrom'];
        $dtfrom_user    = strtotime($dtfrom);
        $dtto           = $_POST['dtto'];
        $dtto_user      = strtotime($dtto);

        $timeout        = $_POST['timeout'];
        $timein         = $_POST['timein'];

        $sql            = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id='{$user_id}'  AND dtfrom >= '{$dtfrom}' AND dtto <= '{$dtto}'";
        $run            = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        if($run && mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0 )
        {               
            while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
            {
                $sql1   = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id='{$user_id}'  AND timeout >= '{$timeout}' AND timein <= '{$timein}'";
                $run1   = mysqli_query($connect,$sql1);
                if($run1 && mysqli_num_rows($run1) > 0)
                {
                    while($result1 = mysqli_fetch_array($run1))
                    {
                        echo "Time not passed !<br/>";
                    }
                mysqli_free_result($run1);
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Date & Time passed !";
                    echo mysqli_error($connect);
                }
            }
        mysqli_free_result($run);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Date passed !";
            echo mysqli_error($connect);
        }
    }
?>
<form action="tt.php" method="post">  
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>User ID : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="user_id" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Date from : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="dtfrom" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Date to : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="dtto" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Timeout : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="timeout" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Timein : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="timein" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

    <p><input class="btnSuccess" type ="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> </p>              
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check each rows for DATE and DATETIME in PHP MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40559978/how-to-check-each-rows-for-date-and-datetime-in-php-mysql)

Comment: it's almost the same . but in this question, i just want to know is there any way to prevent the repeatable output :)